# How can I prevent my embedded YouTube video from repeatedly refreshing?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I prevent my embedded YouTube video from repeatedly refreshing?

I try many ways but almost all of them get 1 error that keeps repeating and refreshing the video

```
getVideoUrl(FileUrls) {
    if (this.loadApiDone == true) {
      var video = "";
      var videos = JSON.parse(FileUrls);
      console.log("videos", videos);
      if (videos && videos.length !== 0) {
        video = videos[0];
        let videoUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video;
        console.log("videoUrl", videoUrl);
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoUrl);
      }
      return this.appService.apiRoot + video;
    }
  }
```

[image of repeating data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZuwR.jpg)

```
<a class="img-figure">
   <ng-container *ngIf="item.FileUrls">
       <iframe *ngIf="item.Type == 0" class="video-container" controls
          [src]="getVideoUrl(item.FileUrls)" type="video/mp4">
       </iframe>
       <img *ngIf="item.Type == 1" class="img-figure" [src]="getImage(item.FileUrls)"
          alt="post-image-first" />
    </ng-container>
    <img *ngIf="item.FileUrls == this.LINK_DEFAULT_IMAGE || item.FileUrls == null || item.FileUrls == undefined"
       class="img-figure-first" src="../../assets/images/default.png" alt="post-image" />
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime angular will refresh the view, `[src]="getVideoUrl(item.FileUrls)"` will be computed again.

So what could you do?

A possibility would be to modify `item` with a new field `videoUrl` in order to compute `getVideoUrl` in your `ts` file when you define `item.`. So in you would have

```
    <iframe *ngIf="item.Type == 0" class="video-container" controls
     [src]="item.videoUrl" type="video/mp4">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: I changed `getVideoUrl(item.FileUrls)` to `item.videoUrl` but the website output nothing, [src] is empty